# why isn't my code working?link list

Tags: c

> q2 to demonstrate linked list operations:insertion,display & deletion//
>
> the compiler code blocks is telling the two error at lines
>
> 73 and 83 which i have marked expected ; before'{' token
>
> and expected declaration or statement at the end of the input*/
>
> but it is also telling that in function create:
> these two error are there !how is that possible when it is referring them to be in the main()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list
{
    int a;
    char name[20];
    int roll;
    struct list *next;
};

struct list *create(struct list *ptr)
{
    int v,n;
    printf("\nenter the value of the inputs");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    struct list *temp;
    printf("\ndo u want to continue(y/n)");
    scanf("%d",&v);
    while(1)
    {
        if(v=='y')
        {
            ptr=(struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
            printf("\nenter the roll number of the student");
            scanf("%d",&ptr->roll);
            printf("\nenter the name of the student");
            gets(ptr->name);
            printf("\nenter the marks of the student");
            scanf("%d",&ptr->a);
            ptr->next=NULL;
        }
        else
            if(v=='n')
            {
                break;
            }
        return(ptr);
    }
}
void display(struct list *ptr)
{
    struct list *temp;
    temp=ptr;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\nthe roll number of the student is%d",temp->roll);
        printf("\nthe name of the student is%d",temp->name);
        printf("\nthe marks  of the student is%d",temp->a);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

void del(struct list *ptr,int c)
{
    struct list *temp;
    struct list *gtemp;
    gtemp=temp=ptr;
    
    while(temp->roll!=c)
    {
        gtemp=temp;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    gtemp->next=temp->next;
    free(temp);
}
main()
{ //73
    struct list *ptr;
    int c;
    ptr=NULL;
    ptr=create(ptr);
    display(ptr);
    printf("\nenter the value of roll number");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    del(ptr,c);
    display(ptr);
}//83
```

Comment: Find the matching braces in your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding the first `expected ; before'{' token` error, instead of

```
main()
```

you should use the full signature

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

for the second error, you should first indent your code properly.

Comment: Is this an answer? The first part is not related to the OP's problem, the second is a request rather than an answer...

Comment: no need to put full signature a '}' was required before diplay defination

Answer (score 1):

check the {} combinations properly. you have mostly written display() function difination inside create{} function. so add the {} pairs properly. add keep code well indented
add one closing '}' before display() function defination.
and

```
 printf("\nthe name of the student is%d",temp->name);
```

it should be %s for strings.

Comment: @user3371423 indentation. code has to be arranged in well formatted manner. that time you can easily make out errors such as these missing }. and even reading code will be easier for others.

Comment: i addded an extra } before display it worked but the n suddely the compiler stopped . why?